# Is there any R function named do_sims() to do a process model simulation?

Tags: r

```r
process_des_mat <- rbind(process_des_mat, temp)

## Do and save process model simulations -----

simulated_procs <- do_sims(process_des_mat)
```

After running this it shows:

```r
Error in do_sims(process_des_mat) : could not find function "do_sims"
```

Comment: @r2evans thanks for your answer! but in the sims package manual, there is no do_sims function.

Comment: Good point, I was a bit quick with that comment ... but the dupe-link is still relevant in that there is a package you have not loaded. If this is for a class or tutorial, go through the previous notes and find which package it says to be using. If there is no package found, make sure you've `source`d all of the necessary `.R` files provided and/or you've written. I can't find `do_sims` as a function in any of the conventional places, so I suspect it's local to you.

Comment: ... and if you find mentioned packages, run `library(packagename)` on each until you find `do_sims`; and if you find a `.R` source file that defines `do_sims`, then `source("path/to/file.R")` that file. I don't think there's much more to do until somebody finds where that function is defined. The dupe-link discusses many ways to find it. Have you tried `??do_sims` or `getAnywhere("do_sims")`?